# Limiting no of locales during rails i18n-js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I am working on a ruby on rails web app in which we are using rails I18njs gem for js translations. On my browser source, I could see all locales' js translation keys are rendered. Is there any way to limit it to only user locale and fallback locale.

gem name: i18n-js

Answer (score 0):

If `I18n.available_locales` is set (e.g. in your Rails config/application.rb file) then only the specified locales will be exported.

Set your locale as:

```
I18n.defaultLocale = "pt-BR";
I18n.locale = "pt-BR";
I18n.currentLocale();
// pt-BR
```

**NOTE**: You can now apply your configuration before I18n is loaded like this:

```
I18n = {} // You must define this object in top namespace, which should be `window`
I18n.defaultLocale = "pt-BR";
I18n.locale = "pt-BR";

// Load I18n from `i18n.js`, `application.js` or whatever

I18n.currentLocale();
// pt-BR
```

Check here for more details : https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to switch from the default of loading all translations in a single `translations.js` file to an [export configuration](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js#export-configuration-for-translations)

This is a pretty simple config that will export every language into a separate locale file:

**config/i18n-js.yml**

```
# bake fallbacks into each locale file.
fallbacks: true

# split translations into separate files per-locale
translations:
  - file: "public/javascripts/i18n/%{locale}.js"
  only: '*'
```

Then you can load only the language you need from the layout like this:

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "i18n" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "i18n/#{I18n.locale}" %>
```